# EKEvent for iOS 6 not working in any way possible

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I have tried asking for permission with

```
if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
// iOS 6 and later
   eventStorerequestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

}];}
```

But the popup just doesn't show up. I've tried numerous examples, tried numerous projects but none work on iOS 6. The apps don't show up in privacy>calendars>. I think I'm going mad over this. Can someone please show me a piece of code that works on iOS 6, where the pop-up shows up asking for permission, and after granting it, exporting the event to the calendar app. Thank you!

Comment: Are you building for both iOS5 and iOS6 ?

Comment: Just iOS 6 I guess. Does it really matter? I think if I were to test it on iOS 5 it'd work, but I'm only testing it on iOS 6 at the moment.

Comment: Well if you're only going to build for iOS6 then you don't need to check if it responds to selector so you can take that out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

First: I think you have a typo (maybe only here on stackoverflow). The correct code is:

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){ }];
```

Second: are you trying on a device? 6.0 Simulator doesn't have calendar app (but has calendar support) and, for some reason, doesn't ask for permission (it returns always granted access)

Comment: Simulator does have a calendar! The only thing it doesn't have is the calendar APP. But you can certainly create and read calendars and events using EventKit

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have the calendar app, I correct my answer. This code works on the simulator in the sense that it's always granted, it doesn't ask for the permission. I can't find any official reference, probably a bug?

Comment: Indeed I am testing on the Simulator. But shouldn't I find my app in setting>privacy>calendars ?

Comment: Not sure ... try it on a real device instead.

Comment: I can't find documentation about it. I can answer only basing on my experience: NO. In the simulator the access is always granted and you don't see the setting inside privacy-calendars

Answer (score 0):

Just do a call to the `EKEventStore`. It will automatically ask for permission if you do.

If it doesn't try going to your iPhone settings: General > Reset > Reset location and privacy
After that try agin!